# Call JQuery from C# PageLoad

Tags: c#, jquery, query-string

Is there any way how to call JQuery function from PageLoad C# file?

Basically I have some selects, some inputs which are not generated by C# code but are defined in .aspx file manually. When I send form get query to another page I would like to set same variables that are defined in querystring. I know how to do that when I use runat="Server" but I want pure JQuery solutions without having runat="server" objects.

Example:

Select input:

```
<form method="get" action="/list/search">
  <select id="txtSearchFullTyp" name="typ">
      <option value="all">Sell, Rent</option>
      <option value="1">Sell</option>
      <option value="2">Rent</option>
  <select>
</form>
```

Now after sending querystring to another page I am analyzing querystring and running function with defined  parameter.

I want to be able to set form to querystring defined as "typ". I dont know how to do it from C# when I dont have runat="Server" option.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code for it. It's quite hacky but nevertheless it answers your question:

```
  <form method="get" action="/list/search">
      <select id="txtSearchFullTyp" name="typ">
          <option value="all">Sell, Rent</option>
          <option value="1">Sell</option>
          <option value="2">Rent</option>
      <select>
    </form>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litJqueryCode"/>
```

and from the code behind you can do the following

```
litJqueryCode.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>$(function(){ $('#txtSearchFullTyp').val('"+ Request.QueryString["dropdownValue"] +"') })</script>";
```